# ordering in regex and LDAP

Tags: regex, ldap

**1).** I am using the following regex for validating email address:

```
"^(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z])[A-Za-z0-9@~!%^*_#$-=.+,]{7,50}$"
```

The problem is that it works fine when the above regex is used. 
But when i change the order of characters in here in the part :

`[A-Za-z0-9@~!%^*_#$-=.+,] to [A-Za-z0-9@~*_-=.+!%^#$]`,

ie., place the characters `'!%^#$'` after `+`,

It gives an exception :

```
[4/8/14 11:58:09:315 IST] 000000b4 SystemErr     R java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal character range near index 38
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z])[A-Za-z0-9@~*_-=.+!%^#$]{7,50}$

How does ordering of characters matter in regex?
```

2). Also i am using `LDAP for registering and storing email addresses & passwords`.

For that also when I give `'!#$%'*-=?^_@testnone.com'` as an input for registration : it is throwing an `"javax.naming.NameAlreadyBoundException"` but when i change the order of characters in the email to `'!#$%'*?=^_-@testnone.com'` it is able to register.

*Basically, what I found was that when I place `'-'` at last(before @) in email it works fine, but when I put it before any other character it throws exception.*

```
How does ordering matter in LDAP?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put `-` inside the `[]` it needs to be first so it won't be seen as a range separator. In your first example you are effectively allowing `[$-=]`; in the second it becomes `[_-=]`, which is rejected as `_` is after `=` lexically.

Comment: Thanks EJP. Can you please elaborate whats actually wrong with the second part as i did not understood completely.

Comment: The ASCII code for `_` is 95, which is higher than the ASCII code for `=`, which is 61, so specifying `[_-=]` as a range is meaningless, like saying `[Z-A].`

Comment: Hey thanks EJP, it worked!Can u please also suggest what could be the issue with LDAP.

Comment: @M42 Thanks. Some people here appear to have no more cogent response than to serially downvote people they disagree with.

Comment: @sonal The name of the exception is self-explanatory. When you change the name, it doesn't match the one that's already there.